# Create Line in botbuilder

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Good afternoon.
I am developing a component in vue js that will be a botbuilder.
The idea is to be able to manipulate the cards on the screen and make a link between them indicating the flow that will be performed. Here is the image:

[image: botbuilder]

It turns out that I have not yet been able to create a dynamic arrow between the icon in front of the phrase "First Step".

Can anyone give me a hint on how to accomplish this?
I am not using canvas.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
<div>
<q-card class="card-wrapper flex cursor-pointer" :style="{ top: currentCardPos.y + 'px', left: currentCardPos.x + 'px' }" 
:class="{ dragging }" @mousedown="startDrag" @mousemove="drag" @mouseup="stopDrag">
  <div class="flex  q-ma-md justify-start">
    <div>
      <q-btn round color="primary" class="bg-green" icon="mdi-play" />
    </div>
    <div class="q-ml-md flex items-center">
      <span class="fontStyle">Passo Inicial</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-center full-width">
    <div class="q-pa-sm">
      <span class="text-body1 fontStyleBody">O fluxo começa com o seguinte passo.
      Clique para adicionar um dos gatilhos opcionais.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-center full-width">
      <q-btn flat label="Adicionar Gatilho" class="borderStyle"/>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-end full-width q-my-md">
    <span class="text-body1 fontStyleBody q-mr-md">O primeiro passo</span>
    <div class="icon-container"  style="position: relative;">
      <q-icon name="circle" size="20px" @click="startLine" @mousemove="dragLine" @mouseup="stopLine" class="text-primary cursor-pointer text-grey-8" />

      <div :style="{ left: startX + 'px', top: startY + 'px', width: lineLength + 'px', transform: 'rotate(' + lineAngle + 'rad)' }" class="line" v-show="isDragging"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
   <style>
.card-wrapper {
  border-radius: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  user-select: none;
}
.card-wrapper:hover {
  border: solid 2px #0bcb6b;
}
.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: -10px;
}

.fontStyle {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #5a677d;
}
.fontStyleBody {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #5a677d;
}
.borderStyle {
  width: 15vw; 
  height: 7vh; 
  border: dashed 0.1em #c9c9c9;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px; /* ajuste de posicionamento */
  left: 20px; /* ajuste de posicionamento */
}

</style>
```

I even created a div that I imagined I would use to be the line and I couldn't get the expected effect.
I wanted something similar to the image below:

[image]

Can I do this using only css, javascript and html easily?
I didn't want to use libraries, I found several, but they are all paid

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To help those who need to do the same:
I found the DrawFlow library, I have not yet reached the result I need, but it already helps a lot with the basics, the documentation follows:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/drawflow#features